# Cutting slots in delrin on table saw

Tags: plastic, cutting, table-saw

I have a table saw that can accommodate a 3/8" dado stack.

I need to cut 3/4" wide x 3/8" deep dados in a 3/4" thick delrin sheet. The table saw is the only tool I have that can really do something like that.

What kind of blades do I need and can I stack them?

It's a 10" blade at 5000 rpm, is that speed appropriate for cutting delrin? How fast should I feed it? I'm prepared to trim sloppy edges I just don't want the saw to bind.

Comment: Just cut it the way you would cut wood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (not all) dado sets run a bit smaller (you might use an 8" on a 10" saw)

You'll want to feed pretty fast to avoid melting.

[This page](https://www.plasticsintl.com/documents/Guidelines%20for%20Machining%20Engineering%20Plastics.pdf) suggests a sawing tooth speed of 1600-2600 feet per minute for Delrin (acetal homopolymer). That would require about a 2" diameter sawblade at 5000 RPM if my math is up to snuff. A 10" blade at 5000 RPM is 13,089 feet per minute. A 6" dado set (if you can find one to fit) is 7,853 FPM. 2" (which I've never seen in tablesaw blades, and most saws would not get above the table, I think) is 2,617 FPM.

You may want to find another method/tool.